# Is there a way read all checkboxes in forms and have one Submit button in a separate form?

Tags: php, html, forms

This question will show what a newbie I am. The situation is this. It's a photo contest.
People upload a photo and to the right on the same line is a checkbox. 
Voters check the box if they like the photo. They can select up to, say, 5 photos.

Keeping it simple, my problem isn't with MySQL, but with the form. Each row has a checkbox, which is a form. The SUBMIT button is the problem. The only way I can figure out to have submit work is by putting a submit button with each checkbox. Of course, that's ridiculous. What I want is to read all the checked boxes and have ONE submit button when the voter is finished. Spent hours on this and can't see how to have the SUBMIT by itself that the voter can click and have all the checked values inserted into the database a one time.

Any notions? I know this sound very primitive, but just getting into this.

Thanks ahead of time for any help

Comment: Please post some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose all the checkboxes in a single html form tag and have the submit button inside it. It'll automatically submit data in all checkboxes

Or

You can use javascript/jQuery to run through all the checkboxes. And submit the form.

Comment: That is how a form works. Got that part. I can "use javascript/jQuery is kind of cryptic to me. Not that knowledgeable of jQuery, though I've used it for simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are all sorts of javascript ways to go out and grab the data you want and submit it, but let's keep it simple.

```
[voteform.html]

<form action="process_script.php">
    <img src="image1"><input type="checkbox" name="vote_for_image[]" value="1">
    <img src="image2"><input type="checkbox" name="vote_for_image[]" value="2">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

... then ... (please note the [RETURN ERROR...] and [DATABASE...] blocks are just place holders for you to fill in code)

```
[process_script.php]

<?
    if (count($_GET['vote_for_image'] > 5) {
        [RETURN ERROR 'Please select no more than 5 images to vote for']
    }
    else {
        foreach ($_GET['vote_for_image'] as $index => $image_id) {
            [DATABASE INSERT OR UPDATE FOR $image_id]
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions. I've tried to work them into my code but have a huge stumbling block. Know that each checkbox is for a post (the posts contain the content which is ONLY photo thumnails).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `checkbox[]` as name attribute for each checkbox and on submission you can address the valiues as arrays

```
  <body>
     <form action="checkbox.php" method="post">
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="a">
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="b">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="c">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="d">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>  

    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
     {
       echo $_POST['checkbox'];
      }
   ?>
</body>
```

the above will give you

```
 Array ( 
   [0] => a 
   [1]=>b
   [2] => c 
   [3]=>d 
  )
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions. I've tried to work them into my code but have a huge stumbling block. Know that each checkbox is for a post (the posts contain the content which is ONLY photo thumnails). The first thing I need to do is put all the input lines INTO the form. Once that's complete, then I can begin using your suggestions. It's not as if I have a form that I set up ahead of time. I can get the ID's of all the posts in an array, but how do I use an array to enter these into the form? -- thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
//HTML

```
<form method='post'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='photo[]' value='1' />
  <img src='test1.jpg' />

  <input type='checkbox' name='photo[]' value='2'/>
  <img src='test2.jpg' />

<input type='submit' value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

//PHP

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['photo']))
    {
        if(count($_POST['photo']) > 5)
        {
           // Display error msg
        }
        else
        {
       // Contains all ids voted on
          $img_ids=explode(',',$_POST['photo']);
       // insert or update DB for the image ids
        }
    }
}
```